# on click of table row it is enableing entire table intead of one row and after selecting getting value undefine

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have table with select option dropdown. THis talbe is by defult disable, when I click on table row button, that row should be enable and I can select value and send that to controller for post api pay load.

Issue is when I click on row it is enabling entire table insted of that perticular row. I am using $index in this able 
Select option drop down I have to create by compaing two json data api, issue is after selecting value it is showing me undefined of that selected value,

JS

```
         var mockData =[{
   field1: "Jason Bowman",
    "field2": "Account Representative III",
    "field3": "Brainlounge"
  }, {
    "field1": "John Diaz",
    "field2": "Tax Accountant",
    "field3": "Tagchat"
   }, {
"field1": "Sean Bailey",
    "field2": "Senior Developer",
    "field3": "Voonder"
  }, {
    "field1": "Annie Parker",
    "field2": "Structural Analysis Engineer",
    "field3": "Mybuzz"
}, {
"field1": "Wanda Webb",
    "field2": "Biostatistician I",
    "field3": "Realcube"
    }, {
"field1": "Jose Burton",
    "field2": "Staff Accountant I",
    "field3": "Npath"
 }];

         var emplyeeTable  =[{
"name ": "Jason Bowman",
    "ocupation": "Account Representative III",
    "company": "Brainlounge",
    "id":1
      }, {
"name": "John Diaz",
    "ocupation": "Tax Accountant",
    "company": "Tagchat",
    "id":2
      }, {
"name": "Sean Bailey",
    "ocupation": "Senior Developer",
    "company": "Voonder",
    "id":3}, {
     "name": "Annie Parker",
    "ocupation": "Structural Analysis Engineer",
    "company": "Mybuzz",
    "id":4
     }, {
    "name": "Wanda Webb",
      "ocupation": "Biostatistician I",
      "company": "Realcube",
     "id":5
       }, {
       "name": "Jose Burton",
      "ocupation": "Staff Accountant I",
      "company": "Npath",
      "id":6
       }];


   var App = angular.module('myApp', []);

    function DataCtrl($scope, $http) {
      $scope.data = mockData;
      $scope.emplyeeTableData = emplyeeTable;
      $scope.isDisable = true;
      $scope.click = function(index){
      $scope.isDisable = false;
      }
       $scope.save= function(index ,id,name ){
       var data ={
        "id" :id
        "name":name 
         }
      }
      }
       HTML
             <div ng-app='myApp'>
            <div ng-controller='DataCtrl'>
            <button ng-click="loadData()">load data</button>

            <h1>Data</h1> 

        <table class="table" >
            <tr ng-repeat="key in data" ng-init ="vm = $index">
                <td>
                  <select ng-disabled ="isDisable">
                    <option ng-repeat=" emp in emplyeeTableData"   ng-selected="emp.name == 
                   key.field1" value ="{{emp.id}}">{{emp.company}}</option>
                  </select>
                </td>
                <td><select ng-disabled ="isDisable">
                    <option ng-repeat=" emp in emplyeeTableData"   ng-selected="emp.ocupation == 
                     key.field2" value ="{{emp.id}}">{{emp.ocupation}}</option>
                  </select></td>
                <td><button ng-click="click(vm)">
                click
                </button><button ng-click="save(vm, emp.name ,emp.id)">
                click
                </button></td>
                    </tr></table>
              </div></div>


      CSS

      table ,tr , td {
          border :1px solid red
      }
      selecte:disabled {
     color: gray;
     cursor:no-drop; 
     }
```

I have tried using ng-option not working .
I am not getting what I am doing wrong .

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/aakanksha0/4u59o3mh/10/

Comment: On click, you want to make your row editable, Right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making a simple mistake, in this when you calling 'click' function you are passing the index and you simply setting "***$scope.disable = false;***" and hence it is enabling all the options as in your code "***$scope.isDisable***" is a global variable, So you need to make simple changes :

1. In HTML while calling 'click' function, instead of passing 'vm' as a parameter with click function, you need to pass 'key' from your first 'ng-repeat'.
2. Inside '$scope.click()' function, create a new boolean key by name 'enableRow' and mark it as true. Your click function will be like this then.

```
$scope.click = function(empObject){        
   empObject.enableRow = true;
}
```

3. Finally in HTML, instead of using 'ng-disabled ="isDisable"', use *** ng-disabled ="!key.enableRow"***, because of 2 way binding property of angularjs, as soon as you call click function and set enableRow as true, it will reflect in the UI.

For working demo of your issue, click on this link : [Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/pmq4oj0d/10/)

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for reply ,it is working for disable and enable , but still after selceting option from drop down, value  comming undefined , is there any suggestion ? 
 https://jsfiddle.net/aakanksha0/gj98mukb/

Comment: Hi Aakanksha, just add 'ng-model' to both dropdowns and pass those values in your save function. If this helps mark the answer as accepted. Click on this link for working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/5houe3sd/10/

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're using one "isDisabled" property to control the disabled state for every select.

Easiest way I can think of is creating a component of each row (I don't know the Angular equivalent) so each has it's own logic.

If you don't want to do that, you can keep a map of rows with a disabled state for each, then toggle the respective one using the id you use above.

Comment: I figgured out disable value, but I m not able to get drop down value after editing .